# When installing dependencies for react native I get "Checking Compilers, build tools, SDKs and Visual Studio Failed"

Tags: react-native, visual-studio

I'm trying to set up a global environment for react native (I assume you can do this as opposed to setting up environments on a project by project basis)

I'm on windows 11 and I've just used chocolatey to download visual studio. I've installed visual studio community 2019, the latest version and I've uninstalled visual studio build tools, because I read somewhere that the package can interfere with pathing priority..

[image: Error screenshot]

When I run the command below. I'm not entirely sure what it's meant to do. Is it setting up a single project or is setting up a suitable environment for the windows OS?

"Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process -Force;
iex (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://aka.ms/rnw-vs2019-deps.ps1')"

Regardless, I get the error 'Checking Compilers, build tools, SDKs and Visual Studio: Failed' when I run in an elevated powershell terminal.

I have no idea how to trouble shoot this. The problem could be in build tools, sdks or visual studio..

I have added 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community' to my global path.

I'm not sure where the most authorative voice on this is. I've read countless github forums from microsoft.

My original problem was a [possbible unhandled promise rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74312131/possible-unhandled-promise-rejection-id-0-typeerror-null-is-not-an-object)

Apologies if the problem is too broad, I've done my best to explain what I'm trying to achieve and the problem that I'm running up against, but honestly I do not know if this is even necessary as I'm able to use the create-react-native-app command without any problems, however there may be some issues later on if my environment isn't correct. It's just hard for me to know what those would be..